# Showing snackbar again after dismissing it for displaying network status in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am showing network status offline using snackbar:

```js
showSnackbar(message: string, duration?: number, dismissTitle?: string): void {
    this.snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(message, dismissTitle, {
      duration: duration
    });
}

hideSnackbar(): void {
    this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
}

handleNetwork() {
    fromEvent(window, 'offline').subscribe(event => {
        this.showSnackbar('No Internet', null, 'Dismiss');
        //After Dismiss Snack-bar
        this.snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
            this.handleNetwork();
        });
    });

    fromEvent(window, 'online').subscribe(event => {
      this.hideSnackbar();
    });
}
```

On each snackbar dismiss I would like to show snackbar again  until the network status becomes online. I am calling handleNetwork() again after snackbar dismiss but it is not working. If anyone knows how to do it then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: You want to show the snackbar while you are offline + you want for the user not to be able to disable?

Comment: Doesn't the snackbar have it's own dismiss functionality built in? Imo you should just make sure the snackbar is shown every time connecting to the network fails. (And maybe alter the snackbar settings to only show the message once.) This way it will keep showing up like you intend it to.

Comment: I am dismissing the snackbar. But when I call again handleNetwork() in this.snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe, it does not show the snackbar again

Comment: If you want a message to stay while you have no connection, you are better of using an *ngIf on some boolean value 'isConnected'... But if you insist on doing this, I am willing to take a look if you create an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
isOffline = false;

showSnackbar(message: string, duration?: number, dismissTitle?: string): void {
   this.snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(message, dismissTitle, {
     duration: duration
  });
}

hideSnackbar(): void {
  this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
}

handleNetwork() {
 fromEvent(window, 'offline').subscribe(event => {
    this.isOffline = true;
    this.showStatus();
 });
 fromEvent(window, 'online').subscribe(event => {
    this.isOffline = false;
    this.hideSnackbar();
 });
}

showStatus() {
  this.showSnackbar('No Internet', null, 'Reconnect');
  this.snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
    if (this.isOffline === true) {
      this.showStatus();
    }
  });
 }
```